# como resolver missing 2 required positional argument python

Tags: python-3.x, funções, argumento

Sou nova em Python e programação e estou tentando criar uma calculadora (meio interativa acho kkkk) usando o conteúdo que estou aprendendo de criar funções,porem está dando essa erro sobre a última linha (onde eu estou tentando chamar as funções, porque quando eu colocava para rodar sem essa linha so processava o programa com exito sem mostrar nada).Segue o erro que aparece e meu código:

> (numero(calculo(mensagem)))
>   TypeError: calculo() missing 2 required positional argument: 'num2'

```
def numero(num1,num2):
    num1 = float(input("Digite um numero: "))
    num2 = float(input("Digite outro numero: "))
def calculo(result,num1,num2):
    calculo = int(input("Digite um o respectivo numero de acordo com o calculo que deseja realizar \n 1-)adição \n 2-)subtração \n 3-)divisão \n 4-)potenciação \n 5-)multiplicação "))
    if calculo == 1:
        result = num1 + num2
    elif calculo == 2:
        result = num1 - num2
    elif calculo == 3:
        result = num1 / num2
    elif calculo == 4:
        result = num1 ** num2
    elif calculo == 4:
        result = num1 * num2

def mensagem(result):
    print(" o resultado é",result)
(numero(calculo(mensagem)))
```

Na realidade deu esse erro com o numero também, mas eu não faço a minima ideia de como resolver, sei que é um problema simples mas estou com dificuldade.Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Vitória seu código apresenta algumas falhas de indentação, não sei se foi falha ao passa a pergunta mas vamos lá.

A falha indica que seu método `calculo` está não está recebendo dois parâmetros e ele precisa de três a falha ocorre nesta chamada `(numero(calculo(mensagem)))`.

Seus métodos devem retornar os valores, se não eles ficarão apenas disponíveis no método.
 Então editando seus métodos:

```
# removi os parematros, não são necessários você que irá informá-los
# dentro do método
def numero():
    num1 = float(input("Digite um numero: "))
    num2 = float(input("Digite outro numero: "))
    return num1, num2

# removi o parametro result, já que ele será calculado pelo metodo
# e aqui ele será retornado
def calculo(num1,num2):
    calculo = int(input("Digite um o respectivo numero de acordo com o calculo que deseja realizar \n 1-)adição \n 2-)subtração \n 3-)divisão \n 4-)potenciação \n 5-)multiplicação "))
    if calculo == 1:
        result = num1 + num2
    elif calculo == 2:
        result = num1 - num2
    elif calculo == 3:
        result = num1 / num2
    elif calculo == 4:
        result = num1 ** num2
    elif calculo == 4:
        result = num1 * num2

    return result

def mensagem(result):
    print(" o resultado é",result)

# aqui a função numero retorna uma tupla, porque está retornando 2
# valores, então vamos receber primeiro a tupla e passar depois para
# as funções
resposta = numero()
mensagem(calculo(resposta[0], resposta[1]))
```

Quando um método retorna mais de uma variável ele retorna como padrão no formato de tupla sem que seja necessário colocar os `()` no return

Comment: Então eu fiz as mudanças que você falou, quando mudei a indentação (nos "if" e "elif" que foi o que acho que você estava se referindo) deu erro, talvez eu tenha entendido errado também. E adicionei o return no final porém o erro persiste, agora falando que está faltando apenas um argumento, está assim: 
     mensagem(calculo(numero))
TypeError: calculo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num2'.

Comment: @VictóriaJulia modifiquei seu código dê uma olhada nele na minha resposta