# TypeError: economico() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'carro' and 'consumo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, argumento

Tenho uma tarefa para entregar pela Universidade. Já consegui o resultado no VS Code com o código adiante (a ideia é mostrar o carro com menor consumo):

```
def entrada_carro():
    carro = []
    for i in range(4):
        carro.append(input("Digite o modelo do carro: "))
    return carro

def entrada_consumo():
    consumo = []
    for i in range(4):
        consumo.append(int(input("Digite o consumo do carro: ")))
    return consumo

def economico(carro, consumo):
    menor = consumo[0]
    for i in range(1,4):
        if consumo[i] < menor:
            menor = consumo[i]
    return carro[consumo.index(menor)]

def main():
    carro = entrada_carro()
    consumo = entrada_consumo()
    print("O carro mais economico é o", economico(carro, consumo))

main()
```

Apesar de funcionar. A plataforma da universidade usa de uma função main(), já, que é a seguinte (há uma particularidade, para enviar na plataforma não posso ter os textos dentro dos *inputs*, o que não influencia; é só tirar antes de mandar):

```
def main():
    entrada_carro()
    entrada_consumo()
    print(economico())
    
main()
```

E o erro do título só ocorre quando jogo isso no validador (o código sem a parte que a plataforma já possui). As entradas para teste são as seguintes:

**1**. (resultado deve ser AUDI):
JEEP
AUDI
BMW
JAGUAR
10
6
8
12
**2**. (resultado deve ser UP):
CELTA
GOL
UP
KA
10
7
6
9

O resultado com o erro:
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0jGz.png)

O artigo adiante não me ajudou (só se não entendi caso esteja lá a resposta): [como resolver missing 2 required positional argument python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/390052/como-resolver-missing-2-required-positional-argument-python).

Alguém pode ajudar a entender, por favor? Grato desde já!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A questão está resolvida (conforme auxílio do: by @AKX)! Ocorre que há a definição economico(carro,consumo) mas na main() não há parâmetros... eis aonde está o problema.

Assim, a definição de arrays vazias no início resolve o caso!

Segue código:

```
consumo = []
carro = []


def entrada_carro():
    for i in range(4):
        carro.append(input("Digite o modelo do carro: "))


def entrada_consumo():
    for i in range(4):
        consumo.append(int(input("Digite o consumo do carro: ")))


def economico():
    menor = consumo[0]
    for i in range(1,4):
        if consumo[i] < menor:
            menor = consumo[i]
    return carro[consumo.index(menor)]
```

Agradeço!